# How to show my application first in list of application

Tags: android

Actually today I installed [FlashLight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.surpax.ledflashlight.panel)application .Usually by default android applications will be arranged alphabetically but this flashlight application will be displayed at the first in applications list
Any idea how it is possible?.I am just curious to know how to do so.

[image]

Comment: +1 I also want to know this. *curious*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'zero width space' followed by 'normal space' as your first character.

`<string name="app_name">&#8203; Zapp</string>`

You can use following as well

`&#x200b;` (html entity hex value)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that, but there's probably a zero-width non-breaking space, or some other invisible or unprintable character, at the start of the label, causing it to sort ahead of normal characters.

But one thing for sure, it is not at all possible with some java code or any kind of hack because thats what defined in the system and no code can change it

Comment: try this \u200B or simply \n in the string appname

Comment: Actually position in the applications list depends on particular launcher.
Some launchers has ability to specify order to sort apps, some do not.

Comment: yup, but they are ordered with some criteria. like recently installed, by alphabets, by most used. But in case of this FlashLight, it is always ate the beginning when ordered alphabetically